# MongoDB: Strange behaviour of sort with pagination leading to duplicates

Tags: mongodb, sorting, pagination, duplicates, aggregation-framework

Here I've just created a collection of 9 documents {id, name}.
All the documents have the same value "A" of the field **name**.

```js
[
  {
    "name": "A",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "A",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "A",
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "A",
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "name": "A",
    "id": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "A",
    "id": 6
  },
  {
    "name": "A",
    "id": 7
  },
  {
    "name": "A",
    "id": 8
  },
  {
    "name": "A",
    "id": 9
  }
]
```

I'm want to paginate this collection after sorting by name (**it is useless to sort by name in my case, but I do that to prouve the strange behaviour**), 3 by 3. (Page size is 3).

When I execute an aggregate pipeline with $skip 0, $limit 3 (first page):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "name": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$skip": 0
  },
  {
    "$limit": 3
  }
])
```

The result is :

```js
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "id": 2,
    "name": "A"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "id": 3,
    "name": "A"
  }
]
```

And now when I want to get the following page ($skip 3, $limit 3), the result is:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "id": 3,
    "name": "A"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000005"),
    "id": 6,
    "name": "A"
  }
]
```

We remark that documents with ids 1 and 3 are extracted again. This ends up with a bad pagination (duplicates)!

How do you explain this, when sorting on non unique column leads to this strange behaviour?

To reproduce the problem https://mongoplayground.net/p/hP7CMtA3b2f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run: sort  -> skip(3) -> limit(3)

Mongo query optimizer changes the query order to: **sort + limit(6)** -> skip(3)

So mongo is making a 'limit' with the value of 'limit+skip'. And sort and limit are not two different stages, but a single stage. And the reason for this query optimization is it is better to find the biggest 6 elements and sort them than to first sort all and get top 6

Hence this strange behavior. Proof explain result :

```
{
    "stages" : [ 
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {},
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "5ceb96f75538551e7d3bcdb8_lav.test",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {},
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : []
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$sort" : {
                "sortKey" : {
                    "name" : 1
                },
                "limit" : NumberLong(6)
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$skip" : NumberLong(3)
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1560596833, 1),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1560596835, 4),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : { "$binary" : "ouhjbA5FjqF/EE4ySVpHdvG8HaM=", "$type" : "00" },
            "keyId" : NumberLong(6691284195030859777)
        }
    }
}
```

Add index on the name field, the sort will turn into stable sort. And you will get desired results.

Comment: And the reason for this query optimization is it is better to find the biggest 6 elements and sort them than to first sort all and get top 6.

Comment: but when I sort on Id which is unique, I get no problem. The strange behaviour comes from sorting on a column that is not unique.

Comment: yes because all are unique. But in this case all are equal. Try query with sort on name and limit 6. You will not get sorted list (based on id).

Comment: Add index on the name field, the sort will turn into stable sort. And you will get desired results.